# JavaScript - Print Odd & Even numbers preceding number input

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print all odd & even numbers (in 2 different fields) up to the number entered by the user.

I have everything down to validate the input (ensure it is a positive 2 digit number), and I can print a message if I remove the For loops visible in my code, but when it comes to print all odd & even numbers up to a certain number I am literally stuck for 2 days now.

Could anyone please point me towards direction ? I don't want all the codes, just telling me if I am completely wrong and should use another method would already help me, but at the moment I just can't get anywhere, and I can't find any similar question.

Here is my entire code so far (including my failing attempt to print odd & even numbers):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x, message;
  x = document.getElementById("positiveInteger").value;

  if (x == "") {
    alert("Input is empty. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("Input is not a number. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else if (x >= 1 && x <= 9) {
    alert("Input is too low. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else if (x > 99) {
    alert("Input is too high. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else if (x == 00) {
    alert("Input is not valid, 00 is not a positive number. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < x; i + 2) { // This is my attempt to add 2 from 0 (hoping to get all even numbers) to each iteration until we reach the number input.
      message = document.getElementById("evenNumbers").innerHTML;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < x; i + 2) { // This is my attempt to add 2 from 1 (hoping to get all odd numbers) to each iteration until we reach the number input.
      message = document.getElementById("oddNumbers").innerHTML;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <style type="text/css"></style>
  <meta name="description" content="..." />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <title>Q2 - Two Digit Number</title>
</head>

<script>
</script>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to C1 Assignment 2 - Question 2 !</h1>
  <p>Please enter a positive 2 digit number:</p>
  <input type="text" name="integer" id="positiveInteger">
  <br><br>
  <button type="button" name="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
  <br><br>
  <p id="oddNumbers"></p>
  <p id="evenNumbers"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should be assigning to `innerHTML` to create output, not reading from it.

Comment: Put all the numbers in `message`, then do `document.getElementById("evenNumbers").innerHTML = message;`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, but this does not seem to work, unless I have done something wrong again. Within the FOR LOOP, I have tried to do `message = "Test" ' (for testing purposes) and then 'document.getElementById("evenNumbers").innerHTML = message', but all it does is make my browser crash (I get an unresponsive page on Chrome). I have also tried to create a separate function (2 actually, 1 for odd and 1 for even), but nothing comes out. Any idea what's the best way to go ?

Comment: You have infinite loops. `i + 2` should be `i += 2`.

Comment: @Barmar ok that definitely helped, thank you ! However that got me to get the input in both fields, where if the input is 10, I want: Even numbers:  0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 & Odd numbers: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9. I have a felling I my for loops aren't the correct way to go for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You need to concatenate all the numbers into a single string, not overwrite the variable during the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following problems:

1. You're not assigning to `innerHTML`, you're reading from it.
2. You're not incrementing `i` during the loop. `i + 2` should be `i += 2`.
3. You need to concatenate all the numbers into the `message` string before assigning it to the `innerHTML` of the output elements.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x, message;
  x = document.getElementById("positiveInteger").value;

  if (x == "") {
    alert("Input is empty. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else if (isNaN(x)) {
    alert("Input is not a number. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else if (x >= 1 && x <= 9) {
    alert("Input is too low. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else if (x > 99) {
    alert("Input is too high. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else if (x == 00) {
    alert("Input is not valid, 00 is not a positive number. Please enter a positive 2 digit number.");
  } else {
    message = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x; i += 2) {
      message += i + " ";
    }
    document.getElementById("evenNumbers").innerHTML = message;
    message = "";
    for (i = 1; i < x; i += 2) {
      message += i + " ";
    }
    document.getElementById("oddNumbers").innerHTML = message;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to C1 Assignment 2 - Question 2 !</h1>
<p>Please enter a positive 2 digit number:</p>
<input type="text" name="integer" id="positiveInteger">
<br><br>
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<br><br> Odd:
<p id="oddNumbers"></p>
Even:
<p id="evenNumbers"></p>
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thank you so much this has resolved my entire problem. I can't believe how close I was from the resolution (I'm a beginner in Computer Programming), and yet so far due to poor codes structure. This is a concrete example of where I need to focus on to improve. Thank you so much.